# AWS EventBridge Rule stopped working suddenly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I have an EventBridge Bus that receives events from MongoDB Atlas as a trigger. I can see continuous PutEvents metric on the EventBridge BUS's monitoring section.

I have a rule setup that basically takes all the events and puts it in a SQS Queue. All of a sudden the Events stopped being triggered in the rule.

No changes were done in the rule or the mongodb setup.

I need to understand if we are reaching some kind of quota?

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: EventBridge PM here

We released additional (throttling) metrics which might help: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/enhanced-amazon-cloudwatch-metrics-for-amazon-eventbridge/

Alternatively, feel free to contact support to investigate.